# Unable to read time series in zoo

Tags: r, zoo

I have a text file with two columns.The First contains dates in format mm/dd/yyyy and the second column has data.There is also a header row. A snippet is below:

```
Date       Premium  
3/23/2011   32  
3/22/2011   32  
3/21/2011   33
```

The series is irregular as on some dates data was not collected. The no. of rows is close to 2500. I want to do some Time Series work on such series.

However,when i type the following code, error shows up.

```
x<-read.zoo(file.choose(),header=TRUE,format="/%m//%d//%Y")
```

The error is:

```
Error in read.zoo(file.choose(), header = TRUE, index.column = 1, format = "/%m//%d//%Y") :   
  index has 2490 bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3 4 5..  etc etc
```

Please help me in getting it correct.

Answer (score 4):

The format should be: format = `"%m/%d/%Y"` .